# How does Celery serialize the task's dependencies and library imports?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I've developed a django app which invokes a celery task to update a Django model. I understand that the task is serialized and sent through a message broker like rabbitmq, to celery worker, which executes the task.

The task's execution is dependent on the Django models and various other library imports. How are these dependencies handled by celery? How is this information passed to the workers?

I'm aiming to use only rabbitmq with django, without celery. And I'm at loss when it comes to how the serialization is done.

Answer (score 2):

It's not passed. Each server has the full codebase. The task passes just JSON of the task name and the arguments.